# Surjectivity of $f:S\to S$ implies injectivity for finite $S$, and conversely

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a finite set. Let  $f$  be a surjective function from $S$ to $S$.

How do I prove that it is injective?

Comment: Have you tried counting elements yet?

Comment: Suppose $x \neq y \in S$ and that $f(x) =f(y)$.  Let $|S|=n$. How many distinct elements can lie in the image of $f$?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Let $S$ be a *finite* set, and $f : S \to S$ a function. Then the following are equivalent:

- $f$ is injective.
- $f$ is surjective.
- $f$ is bijective.

This is really just a counting argument. First, suppose $f$ is injective. If $S$ has $n$ elements, by our assumption, this means the image of $f$ has at least $n$ elements. But the image of $f$ is contained in $S$, so it has at most $n$ elements; so the image of $f$ contains exactly $n$ elements and is therefore the whole of $S$, i.e. $f$ is surjective.

Next, suppose $f$ is surjective. So, for each $y$ in $S$, there is an $x$ in $S$ such that $y = f(x)$; we choose one such $x$ for each $y$ and define a function $g : S \to S$ so that $g(y) = x$. By construction, $f(g(y)) = y$, so $g$ must be injective, and hence, must be surjective by the above argument. So $g$ is a bijection, and $f$ is a left inverse for $g$. But a left inverse for a bijection is also a right inverse, so this implies $f$ is a bijection, and *a fortiori* an injection.

---

Notice that the very first part of the argument fails when $S$ is not finite. For example, let us consider the function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(x) = x + 1$. This function is certainly injective but is not surjective. Similarly, the function $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ defined by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x + 1) = x$ is surjective, but not injective.

Comment: Why is the function g injective?

Comment: @user774025: Because we send $y$ to its $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $f$ is a function there can only be one element as $f(x)$.

Comment: Though technically correct, the claim that "the image of [an injective] $f$ has at least $n$ elements" is odd and misleading. It follows from the definition of a function that the image of any function has *at most* $n$ elements when its domain has $n$ elements. So proving the first part really just amounts to noticing that injectivity implies the image of $f$ has exactly $n$ elements, i.e., it coincides with $S$.

Comment: So these statements are equivalent only when the function is from finite set to the **"same" "finite"** set, that is when $f:S\rightarrow S$ for finite set $S$? or any two finite sets with same size will do? That is will these statements be equivalent for $f:S_1\rightarrow S_2$ where both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are finite and of same size? Just want to come up with requirements for surjectivity to imply injectivity.

Comment: Just want to know if there is any special reason for saying that the surjectivity and injectivity imply each other when the same set $S$ maps to itself when you say $f:S\rightarrow S$ in the answer. I feel surjectivity and injectivity imply each other for $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ for finite sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ of same size. Right?

Comment: Sir is second part why $g$ must be injective? I think because it has left inverse $f$. Am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f$ is an injective function and not surjective, i.e. there is point $y\in S$ such that there is no point $x\in S$ with $f(x)=y$. Since $f$ is a function, every $x\in S$ must work as abscissa in the relation $f$. Hence we must have some $x_1 \ne x_2$ with $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, which gives a contradiction. Therefore $f$ must be onto.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this answer is to supply proof details for the first paragraph of Zhen Lin's answer.

---

For any $k \in \Bbb N$ let $[k]$ represent the set $\{0,\ldots,k-1\}$.

Lemma 1: A function $\sigma: [n] \to [n-1]$ can't be injective.
Proof
To get a contradiction assume we can write

$\tag 1 \sigma: [n] \to [n-1] \quad \text{is an injection with } n-1 \ge 1$

If necessary we can apply a transposition

$\quad \big(n-2 \;\; \sigma(n-1) \big) \circ \sigma$

and therefore claim the existence of another injection

$\tag 2 \sigma_{|}: [n-1] \to [n-2] \quad \text{is an injection with } n-2 \ge 1$

Using the [method of infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) we conclude that the lemma must be true. $\quad \blacksquare$

Proposition 2: An injective function $f: S \to S$ on a finite set $S$ must also be a surjection.
Proof
To get a contradiction assume $a \in S$ is not in the range of $f$. We can put $S$ into a bijective correspondence

$\tag 3 \kappa: S \to [n] \quad \text{where } \kappa(a) = n-1$

The injective function $\kappa \circ f \circ \kappa^{-1}: [n] \to [n]$ doesn't have $n-1$ in its range, and by applying lemma 1 we arrive at the contradiction. $\quad \blacksquare$