# Constructing a bijection from k-element subsets of [n] to (n k)- element subsets of [n]

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

I'm trying to get this going I've been working on it for a little while

Comment: Hall's Marriage Theorem guarantees the existence of such a bijection (but I don't know how helpful it is in constructing one).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126065/for-kn-2-construct-a-bijection-f-from-k-subsets-of-n-to-n-k-subse