# If $X$ is a finite set of cardinality $n$, where $n$ exists in $P$, show that the following conditions on a function $f: X \to X$ are equivalent:

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, cardinals

(a) $f$ is an injection
(b) $f$ is a surjection
(c) $f$ is a bijection

I know that (c) implies (a) and (b) and (a) and (b) imply (c). I also have the following definition that I've been playing around with:

If there exists a bijection from the set $X$ to the set $Y$, we write $ \#X=\#Y$ and we say that the sets $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality.

Since we are dealing with $f: X\to X$, does that imply that $f$ is an injection (since $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\to x_1=x_2$)

But I'm not sure what to make of this...

Comment: I am absolutely sure that I haven't got a clue what $P$ is, and why this has to do with injective modules.

Comment: @Asaf Of course, $P$ is the set of positive integers - that's the only reasonable assumption in this context.

Comment: I meant to tag "injection" but got autocorrected. "P" is positive numbers I just cannot indicate that on my computer.

Comment: Well, in either case, this  is quite a duplicated question that has been asked many a time before.

Comment: If you could provide me a link to those questions I would be very grateful. I would not have posted this question if I had found a question that pertained to mine.

Comment: @Asaf If that is the case, then it would be great if you could provide a link.

Comment: @Amitesh: For example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63072/surjectivity-implies-injectivity

Comment: @Sally Asaf provided a link - please see comment above.

Comment: @Amitesh: No need to ping the OP. They get automatically notified on every comment.

Comment: @AmiteshDatta and Asaf thank you both!