# Suppose $f,g$ functions from $ A$ to $A$, f is injective and $g \circ f = f $ prove/disprove that $g$ is the identity function.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I'm sure that I need to disprove this statement, but I spent alot of time trying to find two functions that fulfill the conditions but $g$ is not the identity function, any of my attempts shows that $g$ is actually the identity even I intuitive know it's not. What should I do?

Comment: Try it with a function f that is not surjective

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is right. A solution could be, for instance, $A=\omega$, the set of the natural numbers, $f(n)=2n$ and $g(n)=n$ if $n$ is even and $g(n)=0$ if $n$ is odd.

There are many other example that work, the important thing is for $f$ not to be surjective. In particular, this implies that $A$ has to be infinite.

Comment: A link for infinite cardinal statement: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63073/399263