# Prove $f\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\Longleftrightarrow f([1]_n)\in \mathcal{U}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

Let $f:\mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ a group homomorphism. Prove $f\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\Longleftrightarrow f([1]_n)\in \mathcal{U}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$
$\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{Z})_n:=\{[a]_m\in\mathbb{Z}_m|\gcd(a,m)=1\}$

My proof

---

$\Rightarrow$

$\forall [x]\in \mathbb{Z}_n $
$$f([x])=f(x[1])=xf([1])$$

So can I say $f([1])$ is a generator and then $f([1])\in\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$ ?

$\Leftarrow $

- $f$ is injective:  for $[x],[y]\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $f([x])=f([y])$
  $$f([x])=f([y])$$
  $$f(x[1])=f(y[1])$$
  $$xf([1])=yf([1])$$
  $$x=y$$
  $$[x]=[y]$$
- $f$ is surjective: for $[y]\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ exists $[x]=[yf^{-1}(1)]$  such that
  $$f([x])=f([yf^{-1}(1)])=yf([f^{-1}(1)])=y$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: @Nightflight I guess $G = \Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ and $\mathcal U(\Bbb Z_n)$ means $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^\times$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Leftarrow$ part, you cannot claim that $f^{-1}([1])$ exists, because you don't prove $f$ is surjection.

Since $\mathbb Z_n$ is finite set with cardinality $n$, so when you prove $f:\mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_n$ is injective, then $f$ is automatically an automorphism (as a group, a ring ... any algebraic structure) by the Pigeonhole Principle.

So, adding some details of $\Rightarrow$ part, my amendment based on your proof is as follows.

**Proof**

$\Rightarrow$ *part*.

Since $f$ is group automorphism, so there exists $[x]\in\mathbb Z_n$ such that $f([x])=[1]$. Let $f([1])=[a]$.

Then $f([x])=f([x][1])=[x]f([1])=[x][a]=[xa]$, so $\gcd(a,n)=1$. so $f([1])\in\mathcal U(\mathbb Z_n)$.

$\Leftarrow$ *part*.

Since $f([1])\in\mathcal U(\mathbb Z_n)$, there exists $[a]\in\mathbb Z_n$ such that $[a]f([1])=[1]$. So if $f([x])=f([y])$, then $[x]f([1])=[y]f([1])$. $[x]=[y]$. $f$ is injection, so bijection also.

Comment: Well, not *anything*; the analogous result for topological spaces does not hold.

Comment: @Shaun I meant algebraic structures, but yes, I wrote it a little less clearly.

Comment: That's better (+1).

Answer (score 1):

> So can I say $f([1])$ is a generator and then $f([1])\in\mathcal{U}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$?

Yes.

---

As for the other direction, since $\Bbb Z_n$ is finite, [it suffices to show that $f$ is injective for it to be bijective](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/63072/104041). Your proof there is okay.

---

I'm not sure about your proof of surjectivity; luckily, by the above, it is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help again

Comment: You're welcome, @JhonKnows.