# A question about showing that an injective map $f$ between finite sets of same cardinality is surjective.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $X,Y$ two finite sets with same cardinality and let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ an injective map. Then $f$ is surjective.

I'm sketching down how I'm trying to solve this exercise and I would like to know if it's very far from being correct or is it an acceptable solution. I'm trying by contradiction:

suppose ther exists some $\bar{y} \in Y$ such that $\forall x \in X \, , \, \phi(x) \neq \bar{y}$

But this implies that there exist at least one point $y^* \in Y$ such that $\phi(x_1)=y^*=\phi(x_2)$ for some $x_1,x_2 \in X$, with $x_1 \neq x_2$ but this would contradict the injectivity hypothesis.

Comment: Well...it seems that you are just asserting the thing that you are trying to prove.  You never use the fact that the sets are finite, for instance.

Comment: Ok I'm attempting some modifications

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63072/surjectivity-implies-injectivity-and-conversely) is a duplicate which you can compare your answer to.